# In post-WW2 Soviet Union, did most people have bank accounts?

Tags: soviet-union

Did most citizens in the USSR have bank accounts? How did they work? Plain checking accounts, or was credit allowed? Were banks open 7 days a week like non-religious government is supposed to? Was there a monthly fee for owning an account?

Did they ever get around to using ATMs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Did most citizens in the USSR have bank accounts?

Most families had one or several bank accounts. Sometimes one account for a family was enough, but often older relatives (grandparents) wanted to keep money on their own accounts.

[image]
[image]

> Plain checking accounts, or was credit allowed?

There was no credit on bank accounts, but one could take a loan for certain purposes such as buying things or building a house. These were not connected to bank accounts though. The interest rate for bank accounts was usually 2% annually for call deposits and 3% for fixed term deposits.

[image]

> Were banks open 7 days a week like non-religious government is supposed to?

Bank offices were usually opened 6 days a week, but at Saturdays they closed earlier.

Interesting to note here is that the savings on bank accounts were protected against court action: the court could not confiscate the money from your bank account to pay for your debts. In case you are sued for debt, the court would rule to repay it from a share of your salary, not from your bank account.

Savings book (account book) from 1950s, the design kept essentially unchanged till the collapse of the USSR, but the current design is still very similar. In the 1970s the records were started to be printed rather than written by hand.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

P.S. I ignored the part of the question about "checking accounts" because I just do not know what it is and did not understand the question. Now, after some comments clarified the thing, I think bank checks is a strictly American thing, from movies. No bank in Russia allows bank checks even today, this thing is simply unknown in Russia.

Comment: Is this personal knowledge (and if so, during what decades did you live within the USSR)? If not, could you please provide some sources?

Comment: @CGCampbell it is personal knowledge most relevant for Brezhnev times till late 1980s. But the system was mostly unchanged throughout the whole existence of the USSR, and moreover, it was inherited from Tsarist Russia. Sberkassa (now Sberbank) was instituted in 1841.

Comment: Thanks Anixx, firsthand source is best for these sort of questions. I forgot to ask if they ever got around to ATMs? (I edited the OP). BTW, if you're interested, please join the Soviet Union SE proposal for a USSR stackexchange site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97056/soviet-union

Comment: @DrZ214 No, there were no ATMs ever, and no plastic cards. All accounts were kept using the savings books. Since about 1970s they started to use printers to print the records in rather than writing with hand.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) says the first ATMs appeared in the USSR in 1991: in the International Trade Center and AmEx bureau. They dispensed AmEx travelers' cheques instead of money. The first ATM for domestic clientele was installed in 1994.

Comment: These were not real bank accounts. One could not write checks, for example.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg These were real _deposit_ accounts, but not _checking_ accounts.

Comment: @Felix Goldberg  what bank in Russia allows checks? I do not know any even today. It is totally American thing. Do you claim there are no bank accounts in modern Russia as well? Checks are simply not a thing existing in Russia. I ignored the part of the question about "checking accounts" because I simply do not know what it is.

Comment: @Matt in Russia "deposit" means an account opened for certain term, without ability to take partial sums before the end of the term. So no, these accounts were not deposit accounts.

Comment: @Anixx "_Вклад до востребования_" (deposit on demand) is precisely an **infinite** deposit with an extremely low interest rate and with ability to spend money freely. Technically it is counted as deposit, but practically it's much like checking account (without a check book attached). Such deposits existed in SU and still exist in Russia.

Comment: @Anixx Cheque Books existed in Soviet Union, but not personal ones. And in modern Russia you still need to have a business (_индивидуальный предприниматель_) to write cheques. Moreover, in Russia cheques are quite impopular and useless, so they are extremely rare. But checking accounts are here: those accounts for plastic cards are really "checking accounts" in English terminology.

Comment: @DrZ214 I have corrected the interest rate. It was actually 2% rather than 0.5%. Also there were fixed-term deposits with 3% interest.

Comment: "Checking Account" (in America) is the normal account where you can deposit and withdraw freely. They also allow you to write personal checks if you buy a check book with it, but that's an optional purchase. BTW, I forgot to ask if Soviet Bank Accounts were free, or did they charge some monthly fee?

Comment: @DrZ214 how a bank account can charge a fee? they provided interest rate. Opening and maintaining account was free.

Comment: Well these days Wells Fargo and most other major banks charge $7 per month for a checking account unless you have a minimum balance, around $1500 i believe. Banks make their money by charging fees or collecting interest on loans. You said `one could take a loan for certain purposes... These were not connected to bank accounts though.` so I figured banks either charged a fee or the service was provided freely by the state like healthcare.

Comment: @DrZ214 "charge $7 per month for a checking account" - lol, never heard about this. In America banks take money for you storing money at them?????!!!!!! For what one would bring money to such a bank then? "so I figured banks either charged a fee or the service was provided freely by the state like healthcare." - there was only one bank, the state owned, but the banks evidently do no charge fees for putting money in them even today, any banks in Russia. All banks benefit if you give credit to them, this is evident. The state benefited by being credited by the population.

Comment: Yes it's true. I can confirm because I own a Wells Fargo account and they've been doing it for...around 6 years at least. `For what one would bring money to such a bank then?` Not much choice, AFAIK all the banks (in America) do that. Like I said, if you maintain a balance of $1500 each month (apparently so they can loan out more money), you don't have to pay the fee. So like most such schemes, it affects poor people the most.

Comment: @DrZ214 why would one store money in banks at all then? Now, in Russia there are hundreds of banks, and no one charges for having account. Contrary to Soviet times, interest rates are higher, both in rubles AND in foreign currency (dollars and euro).  I have just checked, VISA or MasterCard Momentum is free issue and no service charge, free taking money from a POS terminal (in the same region), no charge for buying in supermarkets and allows to take money in terminals worldwide, in any country (with certain charge though). http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/person/bank_cards/debet/universal/momentum/

Comment: @DrZ214 Opening an non-plastic-card account is free of any charge in any bank in Russia and former USSR, I bet. Only for plastic cards they occasionally charge (about $10 a year) but only for premium ones.

Answer (score 8):

First, to make it clear, there was a single bank in USSR which worked with personal accounts: [*Гострудсберкассы СССР*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0) (i.e. state workers' savings "Kassen" of USSR - the word "bank" was apparently missing), which in 1987 was renamed to *Сбербанк СССР* (i.e. savings bank of USSR).

> Did most citizens in the USSR have bank accounts?

In the 80s, certainly, yes. But it's a known fact that the number and sum of personal accounts in USSR was constantly rising (faster than both inflation and population growth). So your assumption may not hold for the whole history of USSR.

I tried to do my own (very) rough estimates based on data provided by [sberbank-history.ru](http://sberbank-history.ru), which suggests that it holds only for the 1960s and later.

> Plain checking accounts, or was credit allowed?

Well, if you mean cheque books, then Soviet people didn't use them. So there were call deposits (along with usual deposit accounts, of course), rather than checking accounts. (That book showed in @Anixx's answer is really [a passbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passbook), not a cheque book).

Also there were no credit accounts for persons, but loans for purpose were available. But it should be noted that Soviet state always was both lender and employer, so all credit payments were taken directly from your salary, just like income tax.

> Were banks open 7 days a week like non-religious government is supposed to?

Damn, that was a huge problem for all Soviet people - almost nothing worked on sundays. Seven days a week? Forget it.

> Did they ever get around to using ATMs?

There could be a few functioning ATMs somewhere between 1988 and 1991 (different sites point at different years without a proof), but significant numbers of ATMs appeared only after breakup of the USSR. Sberbank claims it has [functioning ATMs in Moscow since 1993](http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/about/today/historyandawards/history/y1991-2008) - seems like the earliest date.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm still not sure I understand the Sunday part. This seems like a problem from 1917 all the way to 1991. You would think that sooner or later they would get around to it. What is so hard about hiring 2 shifts, one works the first half of the week and the other works the second half? Surely the USSR was capable of this after WW2. Could say the same thing about America today, so maybe it has nothing to do with religion after all. I'm just surprised that the non-religious USSR would tolerate this Sunday business all throughout it's history,

Comment: @DrZ214, What is there to understand about Sunday? Of course, historically, observation of Sunday was motivated by religion. But now it's mostly just convention. People just need one or two days free of work every week, so why shouldn't that be Sunday - after all it's customary. Actually, in 1930s there was a 6-day week in effect, but in the end it gave way to the traditional 7-day week. As to non-religiousness, you might be surprised to hear that until 1928 religious holidays were officially non-working days.

Comment: "the word "bank" was apparently missing" - formally they were a subsidiary of State Bank.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Yes of course people need 1 or 2 days off per week. That's why I said 2 shifts, one would work half the week, the other would work the other half. Or it could be 3 days, then 4 days for the other group, and it alternates. I don't see anything very hard about this

Comment: @DrZ214 Interesting to note here is that the savings on bank accounts were protected againgst court action: the court could not confiscate the money from your bank account to pay your debts. In case you are sued for debt, the court would rule to repay it from a share of your salary, not from your bank account.

Comment: @DrZ214 there was no need for banks to work on Sunday because nothing else worked on Sunday either (with few exceptions). Also while I am not sure if my parents had a bank account, I rather think they didn't. It was my childhood so I am bound to miss many things, but I can't remember any reference to bank or bank accounts in my 16 years of the USSR (except sberbank adverts on house walls). It is also perhaps due to the fact that USSR devalued their currency some 3-4 times and people possibly felt it was better to keep things instead of money (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_ruble ).

Comment: @DrZ214 There is a social value in having a common "day of rest" which was understood by virtually all societies until quite recently, when the importance of being able to shop 7 days a week has seemingly taken priority over meeting and socialising with family and friends.